# What to do as a society if obliterated by sight of humans?

Tags: society, creature-design, science-fiction, alternate-reality, alternate-earth

### **Who are the Qu?**

When a person dies unobserved they give rise to a being called a Qu. This has happened since the beginning of time. They have caused many of the myths of ghosts and gods throughout the ages.

A Qu is just like a regular person except that they cannot occupy the same physical space that is 'seen' by a human(or any creature with a human soul). A Qu obeys all normal physical rules and has all the needs of a normal human, they need to eat, sleep, prefer to socialize and procreate. The Qu shares all the memories of the human it spawned from, similarities in personality may or may not be coincidental.

If a body/hand/atom of a Qu is caught in a direct sightline of a human it is repulsed by the speed of light until distance/lightdispersion renders it utterly invisible to the viewer.

**Example:**
If a Qu is standing in a room and a human walks in and looks around, the human sees nothing unusual and the Qu is crushed into the wall instantly. The energy from the impact obliterates the very atoms of the Qu in an instant and the energy from the impact is dispersed evenly throughout the entire multiverse. The 'vision' of the human is a very physical object in the Qu plane of existence. If a human stood still and watched continuously a Qu would see the human's vision field as a blur and could approach, touch it and climb it.

The Qu population on earth is unknown, but presumed 'small'. In human cities Qus are almost non-existent and their lives tends to come to abrupt tragic ends. Due to their nature Qu's are drawn to the wilderness where there are few humans around. Entire villages of Qus can be wiped out by a single hiker if they are not careful, so they are, very careful that is.

Only direct observation causes a Qu to be repulsed. A human looking at a digital camera feed does not affect a Qu, the Qu can be perfectly observed. Lenses, glass or reflection does not offer a Qu any protection. The technology in modern times have had both positive and negative impacts on the Qu communities. It is matter of time before concrete evidence rallies the humans to serious investigation, this far they are undetected by the scientific community.

**Questions:**

How would the organized Qu communities handle the emerging situation?

And how would they go about achieving their goals?

[Variables such as 'how clothing works' can be defined if need be]

Comment: What is the natural lifespan of a Qu? Do they die of natural causes? You indicate a desire to procreate, can they have Qu children?

Comment: They are like humans in those matters, disease, aging, health. If they are spawned from a human death they begin their existence at the age of the deceased. If they are the result of lovemaking between two Qus, they are born just like a human child.

Comment: How do you handle Qu being seen by a camera? Are they obliterated by the *camera* itself or only if someone is watching a live feed? What about a recording viewed after the fact?

Comment: Since you said this could be defined....how does clothing work? If a Qu wore a full-body obscuring suit with cameras as their primary means of vision...would they be protected or not? Also: Are Qu naturally aware of this phenomenon? i.e. are they born with the awareness that being seen means death?

Comment: Each of the questions you have asked are far too broad, story based and opinion based for this site.

Comment: So that's why some Arab nations keep their women fully hidden inside their enveloping burqas! _They are qus_.

Comment: re: the clothing all-covered-up thing: Personally I think that would make the most 'sense' That none of the supernatural characteristics of the being carries over to its clothing. I'd see the same problem if you were to imagine beings with invisibility or teleportation, imo its hard to solve nicely without resorting to pure magic.

Comment: No they are not aware, the vast majority just gets looked at and annihilates. Some however get rescued by experienced Qu's and some figure it out by other means

Comment: Two questions; do the Qu exist in the physical world? You compare them to ghosts but I get the feeling you intend them to be normal humans who just can never be seen as they are destroyed by human vision rather than incorporeal beings. And how far does the destructive / physical capability of human sight extend? For example would a person on top of a mountain looking around kill all the Qu for tens of miles around? or would those furthest away feel a physical force but not be destroyed?

Comment: Correct, they are corporeal beings. They can write a letter and post it in the mail to communicate with humans or even talk to them. The physicality of the vision is dependent on the 'resolution' and consciousness of the onlooker. If a hiker stands at the bottom of a valley and looks up at a glacier far away a Qu would _not_ be visible as a small black speck on the glacier. The physical field would push just as hard furthest out. Shrödingers cat/'quantum' inspired, if that gives any insight.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Adam. Please note that you can notify one user per comment using the '@<username>' syntax. This ensures users see your responses to their questions/comments.

Comment: It definitely explains why ghosts are in abandoned buildings and why they try to scare people and why avoid attention

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Adam*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Your question is currently on hold as it seems to be too broad to answer everything you asked in a normal answer. Putting a question on hold is pretty normal and prevents answers, as you need to edit your question to narrow it down, which could invalidate existing answers. Invalidating answers is frowned upon. When you edit your question it will automatically be put into the reopen review queue.

Comment: A problem I see with your question is that you are the only one who can say how your creatures would approach a certain situation. None of us can know. Furthermore this question is similar to "How would this change affect (my own) society?" which is almost always too broad. There are a lot of aspects to society. Is there something you are especially interested in? For future questions I recommend giving the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on [Meta] a try. There you can get feedback before releasing the question onto Main.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description I would expect most human deaths to either not result in a Qu (they were observed during death) or have a very short lived Qu (the Qu would shortly after death/birth be observed and destroyed by nearby humans.)

I would also expect that any mature Qu, who understood that human observation would destroy them, would stay as far away from humans as possible.  This understanding would need to be innate, otherwise almost everyone's response to dying and coming back would be to look for someone to tell, thus leading to their observation and destruction.

In this situation I would expect the most long lived Qu communities to be in isolated locations living very primitive lifestyles; similar to isolated tribes deep in the jungles or forested wilderness areas of the world.  This would make it even harder for any newly born Qu to find their way to these isolated communities.  I would expect almost no contact between these existing primitive Qu communities and new human formed Qu.

The more interesting Qu society which could form would be one on the border or within human civilization.  These groups would need methods of hiding; isolated safe houses, closed cars with human drivers for transport, and means of obtaining goods without human interaction.  Most of these would be very difficult to do in past societies, but would be very possible with the current digital society.

Some other issues/ideas:

- Expect them to use traps or other passive techniques to keep humans away from their settlements.
- Do they search for newly born Qu, or seek out specific people to gain specific knowledge etc. (i.e. follow that civil engineer hiker in case he has an accident, we need some more building expertise)
- Would they start killing humans under the right circumstances to produce Qu.
- A Qu having the age of the deceased human would make old Qu short lived, and less valuable to society (they might also be annoyed at being killed) and might lead to systemic infanticide to "harvest" new Qu children from dead human ones.
- Retaining knowledge of the human could have some odd effects, possibly allowing the Qu to masquerade as their dead human selves. (i.e. that recluse billionaire who only communicates over the camera and intercomm, keeps issuing orders, but on inspection the cleaning crew found a body that had been dead for weeks.)
- They would need human intermediates to interact with other humans for them, these intermediates may form a fringe group around the Qu society.

Comment: Ouu they could indeed engineer the circumstances to create more of themselves by killing people in isolation. I think they would prefer victims in the prime of their lives instead of infanticide though

Comment: My friend's roomate's brother totally stopped meeting with his family after taking up geocaching through a facebook club. He sent some weird emails and texts for a few days, like he didn't remember some family details. Now he skypes so they know he's ok, but he moved out west somewhere and isn't very specific where. I thought maybe it's a cult, but his new friends chat with us and seem cool just some of them have a funny accent.

Answer (score 2):

They would by necessity become masters of camouflage, likely hate humans, (wouldn't you hate something that could kill you with a glance?) and live in caves and/or underground when possible.

Their weapons would likely involve set traps, ranged weapons, and anything that could obscure sight or blind people.

They would be sparse in number, with only the tiniest fraction of them living long enough to make it to others of their kind.  Urban environments would have a very low survival rate while those in the country would have a higher rate.

They would need some method of detecting humans at great distances, and ways of approaching without being seen.

They would increase their numbers by trapping humans in such a way so that the humans would die unobserved, and would be responsible for all the "missing persons" cases being reported.

Any hiker or traveler in their claimed areas would gain special attention and their deaths all the more painful as they would be perceived as an invader with ill designs.